# How to access StartActivityForResult() from SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-activity

I want to create a class to handle everything to do with images for my application.

It made sense to extend SQLiteOpenHelper for to do this, since most of its work is done in a database.

One of my methods returns a ViewGroup object that I can incorporate in several higher-level layouts.  This ViewGroup contains a group of pictures, and a button to add new images.

My problem comes when I want to handle the button click with a **startActivityForResult()** action - which is a part of the Activity class, and **not available in the SQLiteOpenHelper** class.

**Am I approaching this wrong?**  Or is there a way I can access startActivityForResult() (and onActivityResult()) from within my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work by passing an **Activity** as a parameter to the class, and then using:

myActivity.startActivityForResult(...

Answer (score 1):

> extend SQLiteOpenHelper for to do this

That class shall just *open* your database file (and create the tables you need), nothing more. You should write another database handling class that uses the open[ing]Helper class to open the database and which does all the inserting / updating in the database.

> Am I approaching this wrong?

Imo Yes. The user event logic is responsibility of the Activity so it should be there or in a class where you delegate all that.

The database functionality should be used from there - at best asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As Brent said, and pass `getParent()` as a parameter to your method.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to split what you are doing extend the activity instead of SQLiteOpenHelper and have another class say MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper have all the database stuff in this class and create an object of this in your activity for any database communications this will be better to handle and make changes.